# Find a regular expression for repeated words in a code

Tags: regex

i have many MySQL queries using "AS" and the same column name as alias.

Example:

```
`table1`.`field112` AS `field112`,
`table1`.`field113` AS `field113`,
`table1`.`field114` AS `field114`,
```

so, i want to replace them simply for:

```
`table1`.`field112`,
`table1`.`field113`,
`table1`.`field114`,
```

So I tried some regular expresion like this:

```
/(`\w+`) AS (`\w+`)/g
```

This solve the problem replacing the text for $1.

Then i found this:

```
`table1`.`field137` AS `aliased_field`,
```

Using the regular expression this line turn into this:

```
`table1`.`field137`,
```

This destroy the query, so, i need to change my regular expression to select all the texts when $1 and $2 are the same text only.

There are any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *backreference*:

```
/(`\w+`) AS \1/g
```

The term `\1` means "what was captured in group 1" (works for groups 1 through 9).